# Join array field of objectid with filter and limit - MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

Does anyone know how to get the desired result below with some requirements? I can't think of much efficient way and hoping that experts can help me. :)

Thank you very much in advance.

---

Playlist Document

```
"_id" : "playlist1", "title" : "Sample Playlist", 
"items" : ["item3", "item2", "item1", "item5", "item4"] // These are ObjectId type
```

Items Collection

```
{ "_id" : "item1", "type" : "video", "playlist": "playlist1" }
{ "_id" : "item2", "type" : "music", "playlist": "playlist1" }
{ "_id" : "item3", "type" : "video", "playlist": "playlist1" }
{ "_id" : "item4", "type" : "music", "playlist": "playlist1" }
{ "_id" : "item5", "type" : "video", "playlist": "playlist1" }
{ "_id" : "item6", "type" : "video", "playlist": "playlist2" } // Different playlist
```

#### Requirements

- Limit to **2** with skip
- Only type of **video**
- Maintain order as in **items** array field in playlist document
- Efficient way as items can be huge array (like 1000+)

#### Desired Result

Page 1:

```
{ "_id" : "item3", "type" : "video", "playlist": "playlist1" } // Maintain order
{ "_id" : "item1", "type" : "video", "playlist": "playlist1" }
```

Page 2:

```
{ "_id" : "item5", "type" : "video", "playlist": "playlist1" }
```

Comment: What is your mongo server version ?

Comment: I can use 3.4..

Comment: I'm thinking of projecting the index of item from array and then sort and limit it.

Comment: Yes you've the right idea. See if you can work with this for now. http://www.kamsky.org/stupid-tricks-with-mongodb/using-34-aggregation-to-return-documents-in-same-order-as-in-expression. I'll try to add an answer shortly.

Comment: Another option is using `$unwind` then `$lookup` then `$filter`. Just curious though about performance.

Comment: Damn. Didn't know that Mongoose populate does the trick!
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-populate

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {$match: {_id: "playlist1"}},
    {$unwind: {path: "$items", includeArrayIndex: 'item_index'}},
    {$limit: 2},
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "items",
            localField: "items",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "items"
        }
    },
    {$sort: {item_index: 1}},
    {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: {$arrayElemAt: ["$items", 0]}}}
])
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use $sort $skip $limit of mongodb to get the desired object

```
db.Items.aggregate({
            $match: {"type":"video"}
        }, {
            $sort: {
                KEY_TO_SORT: -1
            }
        }, {
            $skip: parseInt(skip)
        }, {
            $limit: parseInt(limit)
        },
        function (err, success) {
       // Error and success comes here
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But that does not sort according to `playlist.items` array. I'm looking deeply with `$unwind` operator now.